# Projective embedding of a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have been studying projective embeddings, and I am a bit confused. Let 
$$\pi: C\to T$$
with $C$ curve of $g\geq 3$. We have a canonical very ample sheaf, which is $\omega_{C/T}^{\otimes 3}$. Why do we have a closed injective map as follows?
$$C\hookrightarrow \operatorname{Proj}(\pi_*\omega_{C/T}^{\otimes 3})$$

Comment: This is the difinition of a very ample sheaf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the definition of a very ample sheaf plus the definition of a projective/proper curve.

> **Definition** (Stacks [01VM](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01VM)): Let $f:X\to S$ be a morphism of schemes. Let $\mathcal{L}$ be an invertible $\mathcal{O}_X$-module. We say that $\mathcal{L}$ is relatively very ample (or more precisely $f$-relatively very ample) if there exists a quasicoherent $\mathcal{O}_S$-module $\mathcal{E}$ and an immersion $i:X\to \Bbb P(\mathcal{E})=\underline{\operatorname{Proj}}_S(\operatorname{Sym}(\mathcal{E}))$ so that $\mathcal{L}=i^*\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P(\mathcal{E})}(1)$.

Assuming you take your curve to be proper (or projective, which implies proper), then every map out of it is a closed map, so $i$ must then be a closed immersion. As immersions are injective, we see what you're requesting.